# Change button back color after click, and change it back after 2nd click and so on

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

hi guys i am create 10 button and add my panel. its works. I want to change the button.background color when I click again on the button and I want the same color to turn. tha

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Size = new Size(43, 43);
            button.Tag = i;
            button.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClickOneEvent);
           button.Location = new Point(60, 60 + (i * 50));
          }
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(button);
        }
    }

    void ButtonClickOneEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MouseEventArgs me = (MouseEventArgs)e
        Button button = sender as Button;
        if (button != null)
        {
            switch ((int)button.Tag)
            {
                case 0:
                    if (me.Clicks >= 2)
                    { 
                        button.BackColor = Color.White;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        button.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    button.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    button.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you want to alternate between white and red background for each click?

Comment: I want it exactly like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what you want is to change background color in every mouse click you could do something like:

```
void ButtonClickOneEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    if (btn != null)
    {
         btn.BackColor = (btn.BackColor == Color.White) ? Color.Red : Color.White;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would take out the check for null. I would imagine if the click event ever passed a null object for sender that there should be an exception, and I'm not even sure how that would happen anyways.

Comment: @BlakeThingstad I just checked for the `null` out because in principle you can use that method for several kind of  events and not just for button's click events. But, if in your code you're absolutely sure it's only for button's click events then I guess the check is there for nothing. :)

Comment: Fair enough, not like it's impeding performance or anything, just a little cleaner looking without it